# Run a command in a makefile and print STDERR / STDOUT to both the terminal and a text file

Tags: windows, cmd, makefile, gnu-make

First off, I'm using GNU Make 4.3 on Windows 10. I previously tried GNU Make 4.2.1, which gave me the exact same results as 4.3.

Anyway, I have a very simple makefile that does (or at least is intended to do) nothing more than run a simple command and print the output of that command (both stderr and stdout) to the terminal and to a text file.

```
$(info $$(MAKECMDGOALS) is "$(MAKECMDGOALS)". $$(SHELL) is \
"$(SHELL)". $$(MAKESHELL) is "$(MAKESHELL)". $$(COMSPEC) is "$(COMSPEC)". $$(OS) is "$(OS)".)

TEE := C:\tools\UnixTools\usr\local\wbin\tee.exe

LOG_FILE := C:\Temp\loggy__.txt

.PHONY : meep

all : meep

meep :
    $(info Making meep.)
    $(info Running command {dir 2>&1 | $(TEE) $(LOG_FILE)}.)
    $(shell dir 2>&1 | $(TEE) $(LOG_FILE))
```

The last line is the one that is giving me trouble. Two things are happening that run counter to my expectations:

1. While the `$(shell ...)` call does print the output of the `dir` command both to my text file and the terminal, the output on the terminal is weirdly formatted. Where normally, `dir` prints one element per line, here I'm getting the entire output in one line, so it seems like GNU Make (or something else) somehow removes the newline characters from the output before it is shown in the terminal window.
2. In addition, I'm getting a `The system cannot find the file specified.` error message (and as usual, Windows is not nice enough to tell me which file it is that it cannot find). Running an `echo %errorlevel%` in the same CMD shell in which I ran GNU Make confirms that the Make call errored out (exit status is 2).

Weirdly enough, if I run the command `dir 2>&1 | C:\tools\UnixTools\usr\local\wbin\tee.exe C:\Temp\loggy__.txt` directly in the CMD window, everything works exactly as one would expect, without any errors whatsoever, so I'm thinking there's either something wrong with GNU Make's `$(shell ...)` function, or I'm using it wrong. Does anyone spot something silly in how I'm trying to use the `$(shell ...)` function?

I just added --debug=a to my make call to get extra debug output, and I found the following in the output:

```
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\mkemp\AppData\Local\Temp\make23400-1.bat
Batch file contents:
    @echo off
    dir 2>&1 | C:\tools\UnixTools\usr\local\wbin\tee.exe C:\Temp\loggy__.txt
CreateProcess(C:\Users\mkemp\AppData\Local\Temp\make23400-1.bat,C:\Users\mkemp\AppData\Local\Temp\make23400-1.bat,...)
Main thread handle = 00000000000000B4
Cleaning up temporary batch file C:\Users\mkemp\AppData\Local\Temp\make23400-1.bat
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\mkemp\AppData\Local\Temp\make23400-2.bat
Batch file contents:
    @echo off
    Volume in drive C is Windows  Volume Serial Number is 045A-E422   Directory of C:\tools\UnixTools\usr\local\wbin (... the rest of the output) 
CreateProcess(C:\Users\mkemp\AppData\Local\Temp\make23400-2.bat,C:\Users\mkemp\AppData\Local\Temp\make23400-2.bat,...)
```

So it appears that GNU Make's `$(shell ...)` function somehow interprets the output produced by the `dir` call as an additional command it needs to run, which is nonsense, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Using* `$(shell)` is nonsense here.  `make` is acting exactly like you instructed it.

The proper solution is to not add the `$(shell ...)` function call where it makes no sense.

```
meep :
    $(info Making meep.)
    $(info Running command {dir 2>&1 | $(TEE) $(LOG_FILE)}.)
    dir 2>&1 | $(TEE) $(LOG_FILE)
```

Of course, using `$(info ...)` in a recipe is probably bogus. Inside each recipe, you are running the shell; use the shell's syntax to print diagnostic messages.

```
meep:
    @echo Making meep. >&2
    @echo Running command '{dir 2>&1 | $(TEE) $(LOG_FILE)}.' >&2
    dir 2>&1 | $(TEE) $(LOG_FILE)
```

Better yet, don't run `make -s` and let `make` itself print what commands it is running, as it does by default (if you don't sprinkle your Makefile with `@` before all commands to make it harder to debug).

Comment: You know what, it seems that A) you're right and B) I oversimplified my problem. Because while just dropping the shell call in my minimal example solves the issue for that example, it does not in my actual problem. I need to do some more debugging, I guess. Still I'll accept your answer, as it is correct in the context of this question.

Comment: Turns out that the actual culprit was an $(eval undefine VAR_NAME) I had in a function that is called by a target recipe. I've been using $(eval ...) to define and undefine a ton of target-specific variables so I could do some imperative programming in a target's recipe, and in one function I had a series of $(eval undefine ...)s at the end to remove those variables once I was done with them. Apparently GNU Make doesn't like that. :(

Comment: Something you have to remember clearly is that `make` will expand ALL variables and all functions, from all lines in the entire recipe, before it starts any part of that recipe.  So you can't use `make` functions etc. in a recipe that you expect to be run _after_ the shell operations in a recipe are invoked.